# filtering query for django mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have two views with embedded document and list field and need `filteringquery`
for below criteria:

```
class myfriends(EmbeddedDocument):
    myfriends_ids = StringField()
        status = StringField()

class Friends(Document):
    friend1 = ReferenceField(User)
        myfriendslist = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(myfriends))
```

And stored values just like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("542506f9bed069156ddd4476"), 
    "friend1" :     ObjectId("542314b7bed0691c5302662c"), 
    "myfriendslist" : [ 
        { 
            "myfriends_ids" : "5421ae74bed0691471e95b92", 
            "status" : "1" 
        } ]
}
```

I want query to get specific record based on `friend1` and `myfriends_ids` in django mongoengine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Friends.objects(myfriendslist__match={"myfriends_ids": "5421ae74bed0691471e95b92", "status": "1"}, friend1=FriendObject)
```